# Sort UTC timestamp

Tags: ruby

I want to pull the latest UTC time from an array which contains various UTC time.
I could compare two time stamps in UTC as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require "time"

a=Time.parse("2013-05-03 16:25:35 UTC")
b=Time.parse("2013-09-07 06:51:24 UTC")

if b < a
  puts "latest time is #{a}"
else
  puts "latest time is #{b}"
end
```

Output:

```
latest time is 2013-09-07 06:51:24 UTC
```

This way it is OK to compare only two time stamps. But my array contains more than 2 UTC time stamps  and I need to chose the latest one. Here is the list of Array elements:

```
2013-04-30 12:13:20 UTC
2013-09-07 06:51:24 UTC
2013-05-03 16:25:35 UTC
2013-08-01 07:28:59 UTC
2013-04-09 13:42:36 UTC
2013-09-04 11:40:20 UTC
2013-07-01 06:47:52 UTC
2013-05-03 16:21:54 UTC
```

I want to chose the latest time from array which would be `2013-09-07 06:51:24 UTC`

**QUESTION**:
How to compare all the array elements against each other on basis of UTC time ?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable#max`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-max):

```
a = [ ... ]  # Array of Time instances
latest = a.max
```

By default, `max` uses `<=>` to compare things and [`Time#<=>`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Time.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) exists so this is probably the most straight forward way.

Your timestamps are (almost) in [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8601) and those compare sensibly so you could leave them as Strings and apply `max` to an array of Strings as well.

Answer (score 2):

Exact method is [**`Array#sort`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-sort) or direct one [**`Enumerable#max`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max)

```
require 'time'


time_ar = [ '2013-04-30 12:13:20 UTC',
            '2013-09-07 06:51:24 UTC',
            '2013-05-03 16:25:35 UTC',
            '2013-08-01 07:28:59 UTC',
            '2013-04-09 13:42:36 UTC',
            '2013-09-04 11:40:20 UTC',
            '2013-07-01 06:47:52 UTC',
            '2013-05-03 16:21:54 UTC'
          ]
time_ar.map(&Time.method(:parse)).sort.last
# => 2013-09-07 06:51:24 UTC
time_ar.map(&Time.method(:parse)).max
# => 2013-09-07 06:51:24 UTC
```

Comment: Thanks for different approach. +1